# Why am I constantly getting a black screen in python when using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

so currently, my problem, is that I coded a spacship game with the pygame library, and when I had to run it, it all went fine, and it was going well. (At this point, I was running it off a small laptop screen). After a wee ofs break, I came back to it and tried to run the code, however instead of being met with the game, i was met with a black screen. (When i rean the code, I had 2 external monitors plugged into the laptop). I used Sublime Text for this

So, what I tried was restarting everything and disconnecting the monitors, I also checked the version of python and pygame, I reinstalled those, I tried the code on Visual Studio, on a seperate computer. I even rewrote the code, so that it is short, and only displays a colored screen:
[image]

however this made no difference, and it still only displays a black screen.

I understand this could have something to do witht he files, because when I ran it in Visual Studion, I sent the zip file of the code to the other computer, but what can I do to fix these files? Since I tried to start over but it still gives me a black screen, even if I place the python scripts elsewhere.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You're not drawing anything in your program's main loop.

The

```
self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
pygame.display.flip()
```

block needs to be indented into the `while True:` loop. Otherwise your code is just waiting for the window to be closed, and nothing ever gets drawn.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer, sadly, I tried it, but it still causes the same problem. Thank you anyway!